# urls.py to different project django

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up a Django webserver and I have multiple projects on there and I want to serve different projects based on what domain the user is coming from.

I've tried setting up a "master project" that has a urls.py, and redirect from there to different projects, but I couldn't link to different projects and I don't think that's the way I'm supposed to do it.

I know I can use Apache virtualhosts but it's such a hassle and I wonder if there's a better approach.

Comment: The apache virtualhosts is the way to go

Comment: virtualhosts (apache, nginx or whatever) are much less of a hassle than trying to force django into doing something it has never been designed to do, and will avoid introducing one more unneeded single pont of failure. Also it will make it easier to scale horizontally if the needs arises.